# Can't upload app with frameworks to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to upload an iOS - Swift app to the App Store using XCode 8. Trying to create the IPA file returned an error saying:

> framework did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent"
>   resource

(my app uses AWSSDK and FBSDK).

Doing some research i found that i needed to delete the frameworks from embedded binaries, but doing that gave me another error:

> Library not loaded, Reason: image not found

I'm not sure about what should i do because when i search for the first error it says that i should delete the frameworks from embedded binaries, when i search for the second error it says that i should add the frameworks to embedded binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after doing some research i found that Facebook SDK doesn't has to be on Embedded binaries (thus generating the first error), but AWS SDK has to (thus generating the second error). Also, as a side note, when you add AWS SDK as a Framework you should also add a custom script that removes testing architectures and manages signing. This script (and instructions) could be easily found on the [AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) for preparing the SDK after a bit of cold minded search.